# Nesting elements using razor markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Am working on an Asp.Net MVC Web application,  I am using a theme to replace the default theme and I would like to use @html.ActionLink() to generate a link. My problem is that the theme requires that I nest another element in the html link tag that will be automatically be generated. How do I nest elements using razor syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can nest elements in razor syntax. 
Solution for your problem would be to use @Url.Action() inside href property of a tag like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action( "Action", "Controller")" class="btn btn-info"></a>
```